# Jenkins Multibranch - exclude branches that are also PRs *except*

Tags: git, jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

When setting up a Jenkins multibranch pipeline, I would like to "Exclude branches that are filed as PRs", EXCEPT for certain branches, which I want to build both the PR and the original branch simultaneously.

Example using MASTER:

- Open a PR for STORY-999

  - PR gets built
  - STORY-999 doesn't
- Open a PR for MASTER

  - PR gets built
  - MASTER also gets built

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, as noted [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76838692/jenkins-multibranch-exclude-branches-that-are-also-prs-except/76839646?noredirect=1#comment137226208_76839646) by [David Navrkal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4075721/david-navrkal), the `env.CHANGE_ID` variable is indeed only set for PR builds and not branch builds, you will need to check if there is an open PR for the current branch:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    // List of branches that should always be built
    def alwaysBuildBranches = ['MASTER', 'DEVELOP', 'HOTFIX']

    stages {
        stage('Pre-Build Checks') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // Check if it is a branch build and not in the alwaysBuildBranches list
                    if (env.CHANGE_ID == null && !alwaysBuildBranches.contains(env.BRANCH_NAME)) {
                        // Add logic to check if there is an open PR for the current branch
                        // If there is an open PR, set a flag or variable to indicate this
                        boolean hasOpenPR = false // Placeholder for the actual check
                        
                        // Skip the build if there is an open PR for this branch
                        if (hasOpenPR) {
                            currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
                            error('Aborting build for branch ' + env.BRANCH_NAME + ' since there is an open PR')
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Building...'
                // Your build commands go here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`alwaysBuildBranches` is a list containing the names of branches that should always be built.
The pre-build check now verifies if the current branch is not in the `alwaysBuildBranches` list and if there is no `CHANGE_ID` (indicating it is not a PR build). If the current branch is not one of the special branches and there is an open PR for it, the build is aborted.

That approach allows you to dynamically include any number of branches that should bypass the PR check and be built every time.
But the logic to check if there is an open PR (`boolean hasOpenPR = false`) needs to be implemented based on your specific repository setup and might involve querying your repository's API or using some plugin that provides this information.

Comment: @markalex True, I have edited the answer to address your comment (at least partially).

Comment: I agree with VonC, I don't believe this is possible in the way I want to do it. This answer is accepted because it is the best alternative

Comment: @Achiral Thank you for the feedback. I will update the answer if I find any alternative.

Comment: Downvoting because env.CHANGE_ID is set just for PR builds, but never for branch builds. Original question want to abort/exclude certain branch builds for which exists PR and this answer is doing exact opposite and aborts PR builds.

Comment: @DavidNavrkal I agree, thank you for this feedback. I have rewritten the answer to propose a different approach.